# Explaining Haskell Code

Tags: haskell

I was given this code and told to explain its logic, does anyone know what is going on, new to Haskell.

```
cpfx :: [[Char]] -> [Char]
cpfx [] = []
cpfx [x] = x
cpfx (x:xs) = cpfx' (x:xs) 0

cpfx' :: [[Char]] -> Int -> [Char]
cpfx' [x] _ = []
cpfx' (x:xs) n
    | ifMatch (x:xs) n = x!!n : cpfx' (x:xs) (n+1)
    | otherwise = []

ifMatch :: [[Char]] -> Int -> Bool
ifMatch [x] _ = True
ifMatch [x,y] n = x!!n == y!!n
ifMatch (x:y:xs) n
    | x!!n == y!!n = ifMatch xs n
    | otherwise = False
```

I am having trouble understand what cpfx,cpfx' and ifMatch are doing.

Comment: Could you explain what, specifically, you are having trouble understanding and what your understanding of the rest of the code is?

Comment: I am having trouble understand what cpfx,cpfx' and ifMatch are doing. @puhlen

Comment: @blazing That's all the code. What specifically about them do you need help understanding?

Comment: why do you need cpfx and cpfx' ?@Carcigenicate

Comment: `cpfx'` is not well defined.  It's prone to `index too large Exception`

Comment: @karakfa that's okay, I don't think `ifMatch` is testing what it thinks it is, anyway.

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_read_Haskell

Comment: https://www.explaincode.app/explain-code-tools

Answer (score 3):

Take each function directly and look at it. Let's start from the bottom up, since they each use each other.

```
ifMatch :: [[Char]] -> Int -> Bool
```

so `ifMatch` takes a list of lists of Chars (or a list of Strings) and an Int, and gives you back a true/false value. Now let's look at the pattern matches

```
[x] _      = True          -- one element list and any number is True
[x, y] n   = x!!n == y!!n  {- two element list is true if the character at index
                              @n@ is the same in both lists -}
(x:y:xs) n                 -- three+ element list guards against...
  | x!!n == y!n            --   if the characters at index @n@ are equal...
      = ifMatch xs n       --   ... then recurse
  | otherwise = False      --   otherwise, give me a False.
```

Taken together, you can see that `ifMatch` is supposed to check that all strings passed to it have the same letter at index `n`. It is equivalent to:

```
ifMatch [] _ = True
ifMatch xs n = let c = head xs !! n in
               foldr ((&&) . (==c) . (!!n)) True xs
```

Though it actually appears to have a slight bug. It only checks if each pair of strings has identical letters at index `n`, so

```
ifMatch ["This", "That", "In", "Onward"] 1 == True
--        (^  ==   ^)  && (^  == ^)
```

---

```
cpfx' :: [[Char]] -> Int -> [Char]
```

so `cpfx'` takes a list of list of Chars (or a list of Strings) and an Int and gives you back a list of Chars (or a String). Let's look at pattern matches here:

```
cpfx' [x] _    = []       -- one element list and any number is the empty list
cpfx' (x:xs) n            -- multiple element list guards against...
  | ifMatch (x:xs) n      --   if all @x:xs@ share an element at @n@...
    = x!!n :              --   ...add x!!n and...
      cpfx' (x:xs) (n+1)  --   ...recurse to the next index
  | otherwise = []        --   otherwise, empty list.
```

So this grabs a character from `x` until the characters no longer match among all the strings in `x:xs`, and returns that prefix string.

---

```
cpfx :: [[Char]] -> [Char]
```

From a list of list of Chars (or a list of Strings) to a list of Chars (or a String).

```
cpfx []     = []              -- empty string gives empty string
cpfx [x]    = x               -- one-element list gives its only element
cpfx (x:xs) = cpfx' (x:xs) 0  {- anything else gives the shared prefix starting
                                 at index zero -}
```

---

All in all, we've got three functions that work together to give you the longest substring of the head of a list of strings that exists at the beginning of all strings in that list.

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

safeIndex :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
safeIndex xs n | length xs > n = Just $ xs !! n
               | otherwise     = Nothing

allEq :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
allEq [] = True
allEq [_] = True
allEq (x:xs) = all (==x) xs

prefix :: [String] -> String
prefix xss@(x:_) = map snd $ takeWhile pred $ zip [0..] x where
  pred :: (Int, Char) -> Bool
  pred (n, _) = (allEq . mapMaybe (flip safeIndex n)) xss

testData :: [String]
testData = ["Hello", "Hello, World!", "Hello, Universe!", "Hello everybody!", "Hell's to you, then!"]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let p = prefix testData
  putStrLn "Should be \"Hell\""
  putStrLn p
```

or much easier with `transpose`

```
import Data.List (transpose)

prefix' :: [String] -> String
prefix' xss@(x:_) = take (length $ takeWhile allEq transposed) x where
  transposed = transpose xss
```

or slightly more efficient

```
lengthWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
lengthWhile _ [] = 0
lengthWhile pred (x:xs) | pred x    = 1 + lengthWhile pred xs
                        | otherwise = 0

prefix'' :: [String] -> String
prefix'' xss@(x:_) = take (lengthWhile allEq transposed) x where
  transposed = transpose xss
```

Comment: But in the new code you have, are you literally doing the same thing I did in the previous code, but more efficiently? @Adam Smith

Comment: @blazing that's a difficult question to answer. Yes and no. I'm producing the same results, but through different means. I'm mostly trying to avoid using `(!!)` as much as possible (indexing a haskell list is slow compared to many other languages). Especially my solutions using `transpose` are significantly faster since `transpose` is O(2n) instead of O(n log n) by mapping over `(!!)`

Comment: I see, so allEq and ifMatch pretty much do the same thing but without using (!!), correct? And what is safeIndex doing and what is the main difference between your prefix function and my commonPrefix function? @Adam Smith

Comment: `allEq` is not the same as `ifMatch`. `allEq` specifically looks at an `Eq a => [a]` to make sure all its elements are equal to each other. `safeIndex` is `(!!)` operating in the Maybe monad -- try `"short" !! 10` vs ``"short" `safeIndex` 10``

Comment: I still dont understand what safeIndex does though @Adam Smith

Comment: @blazing I'm not sure what's not clear. Play with it in GHCI and I think you'll understand on your own.